# c - How to set limits for strtol

Tags: c, atmega, atmel

I'm trying out `strtol` to convert parts of a `uint8_t` array containing ASCII HEX values to integer values.  Meaning that bytes received on the serial port is formatted "89ABC" etc. in ASCII values.

But `strtol` converts the whole rest of the received `uint8_t` array from the start position, giving me a completely wrong value.  So I have to do it like this:

```
tempvalue = MerdPC.buf[15]; MerdPC.tiltcmd=(uint8_t)strtol(&tempvalue, NULL, 16);
tempvalue = MerdPC.buf[16]; MerdPC.tiltparam=((uint16_t)strtol(&tempvalue, NULL, 16))<<8;
tempvalue = MerdPC.buf[17]; MerdPC.tiltparam|=((uint16_t)strtol(&tempvalue, NULL, 16))<<4;
tempvalue = MerdPC.buf[18]; MerdPC.tiltparam|=(uint16_t)strtol(&tempvalue, NULL, 16);
```

And this works.  But is there a better approach to this, not involving a temp variable?

EDIT:

Input string example is:

HEX values: 23 31 43 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 **31 37 38 39** 0D 0A

ASCII: #1C000000000000**1789**..

The four bold characters are tiltcmd byte and tiltparam bytes respectively.

Comment: You can't do that with `strtol`. Your method, even if it works, is not the most elegant one. What are those magic numbers 15, 16, 17, 18 ? You could extract 4 bytes at a time into a string and then call `strtol` on that string.

Comment: Note that some compilers don't treat `uint8_t` as a character type. Use `char` instead.

Comment: Those numbers are the element numbers in the received byte array.  15 is a four-bit command ID, represented ASCII HEX from '0' to 'F', and 16-18 are bytes forming the 12-bit command parameter, represented ASCII HEX from '000' to 'FFF'.

Comment: Your code probably has undefined behaviour so "this works" is premature. Show a line or so of input and desired output.

Comment: Have you tried `strndup(3)` or `strndupa(3)`? Might be more convenient.

Comment: I have no idea what `tempvalue` is. You should start by producing a meaningful example.

Comment: I still have no idea what `tempvalue` is, and the example is still meaningless. *Input string example* Into what? *tiltcmd byte and tiltparam bytes* What does that mean?

Comment: Since your hex number is the last thing on the line, you can just `result = strtoul(buffer+15,NULL,16)`;

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with.  Your `main()` should supply a sample input to the function you're trying to implement, and test the output against your requirements, so we can see what you're trying to achieve.  That will really help you get better answers here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
char tiltparam[] = "#1C0000000000001789..";

char temp[5] = { 0 };
strncpy(temp, &tiltparam[15], 4);
int tempvalue = strtol(temp, NULL, 10);
...
```

We still need the `temp` buffer, but it's shorter and more readable than your solution.

Or if you have more conversions like this one in other places, you could make a function:

```
int ExtractHex(const char *hexstr, int offset)
{
    char temp[5] = { 0 };
    strncpy(temp, &hexstr[offset], 4);
    return strtol(temp, NULL, 10);
}
...
int somevalue = ExtractHex(tiltparam, 15);
...
```

Comment: Thank you.  I see there's no way around using a temp variable/buffer.  But your approach using `strncpy` is better than mine. :-)

Comment: Slightly improved version: `char temp[5]; memcpy(temp, &hexstr[offset], 4); temp[4] = '\0';`. Does the same work but executes faster.